# Are there any file-copy deployable web servers that can serve Asp.Net MVC content?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, apache, iis, wamp

I have been using [the Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com/) for doing local development without any huge commitment or any server-style footprint on my dev box.

I'd like to enable a similar experience for Asp.Net MVC 3 and Razor development.  But I'd like to avoid installing IIS, SQL Server, and Visual Studio.  I'd like to avoid *installing* any server software, except via a file copy.  The express versions of VS aren't an improvement, for example.

I can deal with having to install frameworks, like the .Net Framework 4.0, MVC3, etc.

**Questions:**

Is there any existing software capable of this?  Is it possible to bend my existing Apache file-copied deployment to do this and work with the .Net Framework?

If not, what is the least I could get away with?  Is it possible to install some version of the Asp.Net Development Server without installing full IIS, SQL Server, and Visual Studio?

**Reason:**

My hosting provides PHP and Asp.Net support only, and I don't really want to use PHP.  I don't want my in-development or throw-away projects to be public, so I'm not going to use my hosting for development.  I also want to enable the whole "wipe it clean and start fresh by wiping a directory" development workflow.

Answer (score 1):

On the web server side, the closest approach I know of to what you're suggesting is probably IIS Express.

For the database, have a look at SQL Server Compact Edition -- it's an embedded version that shouldn't require installation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Cassini](http://code.google.com/p/cassini/) is what you are looking for. While I haven't got around to using it, for exactly the same target (MVC 3), it has been sitting in my findings a while now, so please report back if you actually use it with MVC3!

As for a database solution, I would go with an embedded sql ce 4